# How to verify not null and skip row if it is?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to compare 2 dates to be able to display the data in a table.
I am doing the following:

```
${this.dateToCompare.getTime()} > ${row.CreateDate.getTime()}
```

The problem is, CreateDate has a null value on some rows so the above is not working.

I have also tried this:

```
<div ng-if="${row.CreateDate!==null} && ${this.dateToCompare.getTime()} > ${row.CreateDate.getTime()}"
```

I need to check first if the row is null or not, but even when it is null, it is continuing after the && and when it hits the dateToCompare.getTime, it is throwing a syntax error because I am calling getTime on a null value.

Is it possible to tell ng-if to not run it if null and to skip that row?
What is the best way to be able to fix this problem and be able to run the getTime() on it?
Thank you

Comment: What is this `${...}` syntax in the AngularJS expression? I don't think that is valid syntax

Comment: It's to get the value of that specific data, it's a .ts type file.

Comment: How can it be a .ts type file? It's an AngularJS expression that lives in an HTML element. This is an HTML file. TypeScript shouldn't be relevant at all here. If you're trying to use TypeScript syntax, which is compile time, inside an AngularJS expression, which is run-time, then that's definitely not supported and will not work.

Comment: I can get the data normally, the only thing missing is that I need it to not continue the expression if it is null, that's the only missing piece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a function:

```
convToTime(date: Date) {
            if (date !== null) 
            {
                this.tDate = new Date(date.toString().substring(0,10));
                return this.tDate.getTime();
            }
        }
```

and called it this way:

> ${this.convToTime(row.CreateDate)}

All working properly now and as needed.